# file_get_contents: get full response (PHP)

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm using the following code to post information to a URL.

```
$query = http_build_query($myvars);
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                        "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n".
                        "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n",
            'method'  => "POST",
            'content' => $query,
        ),
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Is it possible to show the complete header information of the response.

First I used curl, but this took to much cpu.
With curl I used the following option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

And I received the following header information:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2015 07:06:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=File.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Length: 333
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: 0
Pragma: public
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Is the with file_get_contents also possible?

Comment: Tx, that was the solution

Answer (score 2):

```
  file_get_contents("http://example.com");
  var_dump($http_response_header);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Comment: Tx, that was the solution